# Calling Multiple GET Api in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rest, api, http, get

I have created a basic form, that takes in the value from user and hits a GET API, lets say GET API1 and returns the data in tabular format. 
Here is the code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Hero }    from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-form',
  templateUrl: './hero-form.component.html'
})
export class HeroFormComponent {

  model:any = {};

  submitted = false;
  data: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}


  onSubmit() { 
    this.submitted = true;
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:8188/data/v1/Api/res/${this.model.config}/${encodeURIComponent(this.model.start)}/${encodeURIComponent(this.model.end)}`)
      .subscribe(response => this.data = response.json());
  }

}
```

Now if I want to hit another API, lets say GET API2 with same set of parameters, then how do I do it ?

Edit: May be a logic before actually taking in the values from the form - Like to choose between API GET1 OR API GET2 and then proceed with form would help.

Answer (score 0):

If like you mentioned the user can select which api endpoint to use, i assume its being binded to your model so then you can just use this.model.api in your function. Or define 2 seperate urls and chose between the two.

```
let api1 = http://localhost:8188/data/v1/'
let api2 = http://localhost:8188/data/v2/'

onSubmit() { 
    this.submitted = true;
    this.http.get(api1 + '/res/${this.model.config}/${encodeURIComponent(this.model.start)}/${encodeURIComponent(this.model.end)}`)
      .subscribe(response => this.data = response.json());
  }
```

if api value is stored in the model.

```
onSubmit() { 
    this.submitted = true;
    this.http.get(this.model.api + '/res/${this.model.config}/${encodeURIComponent(this.model.start)}/${encodeURIComponent(this.model.end)}`)
      .subscribe(response => this.data = response.json());
  }
```

But if you intend of developing this out further with more functions hitting different api end points. Then i recommend you create an API serivce. https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-rxjs-create-api-service-rest-backend/

Comment: How are you choosing after defining 2 separate URLs as you said in second way ?

Comment: In this example im just defining 2 separate api urls. To show that you can do that. You can easily have something in your form where the user choses an api. So the value of the api will be held in this.model.api. Then you can just swap out api1 with the model.api value